# Error in fetching facebook user friend list

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to make an event managment android app and for that i want to fetch facebook users friend list in my app..but SDK 3.15 is not allowing me to fetch friend list as this functionality has been removed  from new SDK versions..i want your  to implement the same..

Comment: in new sdk you only get those friends which authorize your app and already is in your friendlist of facebook.

Comment: Yeah i know it ..but is there any alternate available to implement this functionality...

Comment: No there are no alternatives. Why do you need the full friends list?

Comment: Yes  , i need complete friend list of fb a perticular facebook user...

Comment: I need it to send invitations to friends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has removed the option of fetching complete friend list. you can do this by creating app, get user signed in, and only signed in user can access it